# how to write the sql command with two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table **salesrule_coupon**: fileds as the following:

           coupon_id   code

             1        Registered_send_5   
             2         test
```

table:`salesrule_coupon_usage` fileds as the following:

```
    coupon_id  customer_id   times_used

    1               1          1
    1  
   ...              14 ...       1..
```

now, i want to select out `times_used` where the `code =Registered_send_5` where  customer_id=$id. how to write the sql command? thank u.

the following is my  but it not work.

```
$sql = "SELECT times_used FORM salesrule_coupon_usage as a 
       left join  salesrule_coupon as b on a.coupon_id  = b.coupon_id   
       where b.code = 'Registered_send_5' and   customer_id=".'$id.";
```

when i put

```
  SELECT times_used FORM salesrule_coupon_usage as a 
           left join  salesrule_coupon as b on a.coupon_id  = b.coupon_id   
           where b.code = 'Registered_send_5' and   customer_id=1
```

in phpmyadmin. it shows

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'salesrule_coupon_usage as a left join salesrule_coupon as b on a.co' at line 1

Comment: Why it doesn't work? what the error do you got? post it please

Comment: Not proofreading your own code is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's an apostrophe (single quote) there that shouldn't be there and you misspelled "FROM":

```
$sql = "SELECT times_used FORM salesrule_coupon_usage as a 
                           ^ 
   left join  salesrule_coupon as b on a.coupon_id  = b.coupon_id   
   where b.code = 'Registered_send_5' and   customer_id= ".'$id;
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have the `'` in from of the `$id`?

It should be `FROM` and not `FORM`

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in your query at the end:

```
$sql = "SELECT times_used FORM salesrule_coupon_usage as a 
   left join  salesrule_coupon as b on a.coupon_id  = b.coupon_id   
   where b.code = 'Registered_send_5' and   customer_id= ".$id;
                                                          ^
```